# I can not start my react ap after creating

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am creating a new React app
after creating it the Json Package includes start, run
but when I try to run it I am not able and it tells me that the Script is unknown

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

I tried to install `gulp` also to remove `node` and re-install it. I am working on `Ubuntu OS`. I tried with the other laptop and it seems to have the same problem. I tried to run the debug, the server opened but in few seconds it became unavailable like in [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40OGQ.png)

Comment: You have to run it as `npm run start`

Comment: are you in correct folder from terminal? try running ls and check if there's your prject's root. (with src and etc.)